# How to design a switching circuit with minimal voltage drop?

Tags: mosfet-driver, servo

I am using a high side switch with BSS84 MOSFET. This is used to power on and off all the sensor and actuators during deep sleep of the uC. All the sensors are working except the SG90 servo. There is a.vpltage drop from ~3.26V to ~3.04V. Which MOSFET could I use which has a low droupout voltage? Would IRLML2244 fit for this purpose?

Comment: "dropout voltage" is a term that applies to voltage regulators, not MOSFETs. MOSFETs have an on-state resistance that determines the voltage drop, at least if you can turn the FET all the way on.

Comment: " This is used to power on and off all the sensor and actuators during deep sleep of the uC." How many things are to be powered by this MOSFET? how much current will this combination use in the worst case? A quick search reveals a single SG90 servo can use upto 250mA (360mA stall). How much gate-source voltage can you deliver?

Comment: Gate source voltage is only 3.3V. It switches on and of a DHT22 and a voltage divider beside the SG90

Comment: @OHLÁLÁ Figure 12 in the [IRLML2244 datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2244pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664bfff25f0) shows about 70mOhm RDS(on) at 3.3Vgs. That should be fine, it would take over an amp to drop 100mV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need a device with a low RDSon and a relatively low threshold voltage.  You’re currently dropping 230mV although we don’t know how much current the SG90 is drawing when that measurement is made.  BSS84 are P-channel FETs and claim an RDSon of 10 ohms, which is very high if you’re going to use one as a power switching device.  You might consider a BSS308 with an RDSon of about 0.06 ohm.  Either way you’re likely to struggle with an SG90 running at 3.3V as they require 4.8 to 6V.

Comment: do you mean an rdson of 0.06 Ω?